# Rails MiniTest can't detect back state (uses fallback location)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

Having some trouble testing redirect_back(fallback_location: 'index'), since it is always going to the fallback location. The page works fine in a browser, is this normal behavior for Rails MiniTest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the back function to work in testing (or at least minitest), you must add an HTTP_REFERER header to your GET/POST request.

`get page_url, headers: { 'HTTP_REFERER': previous_page_url }`